# How to get the consumer list from ActiveMQ Artemis through any method such as REST API or specific management topic/queue?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to know the footprint for each consumer which connects/disconnects from my ActiveMQ Artemis. How can I do?

My thought is, if there is some REST APIs or specific topic/queue from which I can get the current consumer list, then I can polling it every one minute and write those information to a database. Then I can get the footprint for each consumer. But I need to know whether the ActiveMQ Artemis provides these REST APIs or the specific topic/queue ?

I have read the document of [REST Interface](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/rest.html) but find no such APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The management API of ActiveMQ Artemis is based on JMX MBeans, but these MBeans are exposed in several different ways to provide flexibility for various use-cases. Obviously you can access the MBeans directly via JMX. You can use ["management messages"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#using-management-message-api) via any supported messaging protocol (i.e. AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, core, OpenWire). You can also access them [via HTTP](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#exposing-jmx-using-jolokia) using the [Jolokia JMX-HTTP bridge](https://jolokia.org/) which is integrated into and distributed with the broker. This provides a REST-like interface for management.

Specifically, you can use the [`listConsumersAsJSON` method of the relevant QueueControl MBean](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#listConsumersAsJSON()). For example, if you have a queue named `TEST` on an address named `TEST` on a broker named `0.0.0.0` your `curl` command would look something like this:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost" -u myUser:myPass http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"TEST\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=\"TEST\"/listConsumersAsJSON
```

The result would look something like this:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=\"TEST\",broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,queue=\"TEST\",routing-type=\"anycast\",subcomponent=queues",
    "type": "exec",
    "operation": "listConsumersAsJSON"
  },
  "value": "[{\"consumerID\":0,\"connectionID\":\"ae838a47\",\"sessionID\":\"197c9f51-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939\",\"browseOnly\":false,\"creationTime\":1678126625467,\"messagesInTransit\":0,\"messagesInTransitSize\":0,\"messagesDelivered\":0,\"messagesDeliveredSize\":0,\"messagesAcknowledged\":0,\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":0,\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0},{\"consumerID\":0,\"connectionID\":\"ae838a47\",\"sessionID\":\"197ced72-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939\",\"browseOnly\":false,\"creationTime\":1678126625467,\"messagesInTransit\":0,\"messagesInTransitSize\":0,\"messagesDelivered\":0,\"messagesDeliveredSize\":0,\"messagesAcknowledged\":0,\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":0,\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0},{\"consumerID\":0,\"connectionID\":\"ae838a47\",\"sessionID\":\"197aca90-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939\",\"browseOnly\":false,\"creationTime\":1678126625467,\"messagesInTransit\":0,\"messagesInTransitSize\":0,\"messagesDelivered\":0,\"messagesDeliveredSize\":0,\"messagesAcknowledged\":0,\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":0,\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0}]",
  "timestamp": 1678126836,
  "status": 200
}
```

In this example there are 3 consumers on the queue. The actual consumer data would look something like this after formatting for readability:

```json
[
  {
    "consumerID": 0,
    "connectionID": "ae838a47",
    "sessionID": "197c9f51-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939",
    "browseOnly": false,
    "creationTime": 1678126625467,
    "messagesInTransit": 0,
    "messagesInTransitSize": 0,
    "messagesDelivered": 0,
    "messagesDeliveredSize": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledged": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": 0,
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  },
  {
    "consumerID": 0,
    "connectionID": "ae838a47",
    "sessionID": "197ced72-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939",
    "browseOnly": false,
    "creationTime": 1678126625467,
    "messagesInTransit": 0,
    "messagesInTransitSize": 0,
    "messagesDelivered": 0,
    "messagesDeliveredSize": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledged": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": 0,
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  },
  {
    "consumerID": 0,
    "connectionID": "ae838a47",
    "sessionID": "197aca90-bc4b-11ed-a51e-3ce1a1d12939",
    "browseOnly": false,
    "creationTime": 1678126625467,
    "messagesInTransit": 0,
    "messagesInTransitSize": 0,
    "messagesDelivered": 0,
    "messagesDeliveredSize": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledged": 0,
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": 0,
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  }
]
```

There is **another** management method that can provide additional information, but it's slightly more complex to invoke - [`listConsumers` on the ActiveMQServerControl MBean](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#listConsumers(java.lang.String,int,int)). This method takes a few parameters, the most important being a kind of JSON-based filter string, e.g.:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost" -u myUser:myPass 'http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0"/listConsumers/\{"field":"queue","operation":"EQUALS","value":"TEST"\}/1/100'
```

The result would look something like this:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"",
    "arguments": [
      "{\"field\":\"queue\",\"operation\":\"EQUALS\",\"value\":\"TEST\"}",
      "1",
      "100"
    ],
    "type": "exec",
    "operation": "listConsumers"
  },
  "value": "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"52867\",\"session\":\"bbc234db-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939\",\"clientID\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"validatedUser\":\"x\",\"protocol\":\"CORE\",\"queue\":\"TEST\",\"queueType\":\"anycast\",\"filter\":\"\",\"address\":\"TEST\",\"localAddress\":\"tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616\",\"remoteAddress\":\"/127.0.0.1:46120\",\"creationTime\":\"Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023\",\"messagesInTransit\":\"0\",\"messagesInTransitSize\":\"0\",\"messagesDelivered\":\"0\",\"messagesDeliveredSize\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledged\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":\"0\",\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0},{\"id\":\"52868\",\"session\":\"bbbfeaea-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939\",\"clientID\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"validatedUser\":\"x\",\"protocol\":\"CORE\",\"queue\":\"TEST\",\"queueType\":\"anycast\",\"filter\":\"\",\"address\":\"TEST\",\"localAddress\":\"tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616\",\"remoteAddress\":\"/127.0.0.1:46120\",\"creationTime\":\"Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023\",\"messagesInTransit\":\"0\",\"messagesInTransitSize\":\"0\",\"messagesDelivered\":\"0\",\"messagesDeliveredSize\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledged\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":\"0\",\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0},{\"id\":\"52869\",\"session\":\"bbc282fc-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939\",\"clientID\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"validatedUser\":\"x\",\"protocol\":\"CORE\",\"queue\":\"TEST\",\"queueType\":\"anycast\",\"filter\":\"\",\"address\":\"TEST\",\"localAddress\":\"tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616\",\"remoteAddress\":\"/127.0.0.1:46120\",\"creationTime\":\"Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023\",\"messagesInTransit\":\"0\",\"messagesInTransitSize\":\"0\",\"messagesDelivered\":\"0\",\"messagesDeliveredSize\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledged\":\"0\",\"messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit\":\"0\",\"lastDeliveredTime\":0,\"lastAcknowledgedTime\":0}],\"count\":3}",
  "timestamp": 1678809801,
  "status": 200
}
```

In this example there are 3 consumers on the queue. The actual consumer data would look something like this after formatting for readability:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "52867",
    "session": "bbc234db-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939",
    "clientID": "",
    "user": "",
    "validatedUser": "x",
    "protocol": "CORE",
    "queue": "TEST",
    "queueType": "anycast",
    "filter": "",
    "address": "TEST",
    "localAddress": "tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616",
    "remoteAddress": "/127.0.0.1:46120",
    "creationTime": "Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023",
    "messagesInTransit": "0",
    "messagesInTransitSize": "0",
    "messagesDelivered": "0",
    "messagesDeliveredSize": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledged": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": "0",
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "52868",
    "session": "bbbfeaea-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939",
    "clientID": "",
    "user": "",
    "validatedUser": "x",
    "protocol": "CORE",
    "queue": "TEST",
    "queueType": "anycast",
    "filter": "",
    "address": "TEST",
    "localAddress": "tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616",
    "remoteAddress": "/127.0.0.1:46120",
    "creationTime": "Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023",
    "messagesInTransit": "0",
    "messagesInTransitSize": "0",
    "messagesDelivered": "0",
    "messagesDeliveredSize": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledged": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": "0",
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "52869",
    "session": "bbc282fc-c281-11ed-bcc3-3ce1a1d12939",
    "clientID": "",
    "user": "",
    "validatedUser": "x",
    "protocol": "CORE",
    "queue": "TEST",
    "queueType": "anycast",
    "filter": "",
    "address": "TEST",
    "localAddress": "tcp:///127.0.0.1:61616",
    "remoteAddress": "/127.0.0.1:46120",
    "creationTime": "Tue Mar 14 11:03:17 CDT 2023",
    "messagesInTransit": "0",
    "messagesInTransitSize": "0",
    "messagesDelivered": "0",
    "messagesDeliveredSize": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledged": "0",
    "messagesAcknowledgedAwaitingCommit": "0",
    "lastDeliveredTime": 0,
    "lastAcknowledgedTime": 0
  }
]
```

The [REST Interface](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/rest.html) you mentioned in your question is a *messaging* interface not a *management* interface so it isn't not suitable for management. To be clear, this messaging interface was [removed in 2.26.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2260).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested it successfully. However, from the response , it only shows consumerID, sessionID,.... How do I get user(the user loging MQ and subscribing this queue) ? In my ActiveMQ, all user are required to give user and password when connecting ActiveMQ.

Comment: I updated my answer with information about another management method that should give you the information you need.